# Php, mysql script. *should* work as I see it, but don't

Tags: php, mysql

So, I got this script: http://pastebin.com/HHnUWnyB 
The thing is that it isn't working, and I got no idea why, I've looked at it, over and over, and to me it should work, but doesn't. So now I'm turning to the experts!

Instead of updating in the mysql db it just returns an empty page...

Thanks in advance!

Update: found the exact but that isn't working:http://pastebin.com/pQrdQUPq

```
$username = 'test';  // note, isn't this in original script, it's called from a database, but whatever 
if(isset($_POST['generate'])) {
$newkey = 'something';
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `users` SET `key`=%s WHERE `username`="%s"',
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $newkey),
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username));
mysqli_query($db, $query);
};
```

Comment: Any error messages written to logs?

Comment: debug debug debug, prints values , put error reporting on & many wayss..

Comment: We need more info than just **it isn't working** and **Instead of updating in the mysql db it just returns an empty page**. There are several update queries in the code. Which one doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Nothing in error logs, that's why iI got no idea...

Comment: BAD SYNTAX: There are many extra ending brackets, and unnecessary semicolons. Do you use an IDE like Netbeans?

Comment: @CodeGodie saw that, and fixed still blank page...

Comment: @CodeGodie okay missed one... Now the page is displayed... But nothing is happening in the mysql table...

Comment: try placing `var_dump("test")` on different areas of your code. Run the code and see where it stops, this would be the first step of debugging.

Comment: Broken it down, more specifically it seems this is the part not working: http://pastebin.com/pQrdQUPq

Comment: @CodeGoodie it runs the whole way down... But nothing gets into the db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like either `POST['disable']` or `POST['generate']` are not set. Check that those variables are being posted. Theres also a bunch of BAD SYNTAX: There are many extra ending brackets, and unnecessary semicolons.

Also try changing this:

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `users` SET `key`=%s WHERE `username`="%s"',
```

to this:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `key`='%s' WHERE `username`='%s'",
```

So you should have this:

```
$username = 'test';  // note, isn't this in original script, it's called from a database, but whatever
if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    $newkey = 'something';
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `users` SET `key`='%s' WHERE `username`='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $newkey), mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username));
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Comment: Post['generate'] is set, and found the extra}

Comment: ok i see you found the area where your problem might be (http://pastebin.com/pQrdQUPq)... place a `var_dump($query)` under the `$query` line, and let me know what you get

Comment: UPDATE \`users\` SET \`key\`=something WHERE \`username\`="swantzter" @CodeGodie

Comment: ok I updated my answer, try that

Comment: ok I updated again. Try it. I added single quotes around `key='%s'`

Comment: Nice. Good luck. Try using Prepared Statements or even better use a framework like Codeigniter. This will make you a better developer.

Comment: well that was not really an option in this case... It's a 3 year old legacy project I'm set to maintain...